# Querying from CSV files using python

Tags: python, sql, database, csv

I have three CSV files, one has a list of all pieces, one has a list of pieces of type M and the other one of type B. That means the first list contains the two other ones but without specifying their type.
I want to add a row to the frist list that specifies the type of pieces using python, that means for each piece in the first list, check if it's in list M and add an M in its type column, otherwise add a B.
My idea was to create a list of dictionaries (that I can convert later to CSV using a pre-written Python library), it would look something like this:

```
l = [{'piece','type'}] # list of dictionaries

for c in allpieces: # this is the list of all pieces:
    l[{'piece'}] = c['piece'] # adding the piece number to the list of dictionaries from the list of all pieces
    for m in mlist: # list of pieces of type m
      if c['piece'] == m['piece']: # check of piece is found in listm
        l[{'type'}] = 'm' # Add an m in its column
        else: l[{'type'}] = 'b' # otherwise add b
```

This code is obviously not doing anything, and I need help debugging it.

Comment: would you be able to  post a few lines of 'allpieces' so that I can take a better look at it for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary maps a key to a value like so `{"key": "value}` whereas elements in a list are accessed by providing the index so for first element in a list you do `list[0]` to get it. Now if you want to add new keys with values to a dictionary you can do it by adding them like such `d["key"] = value`. If you want to add to your list you do `list.append(value)`. So in your case what you want to do is create a list with dictionaries inside I assume ? So that could look like that:

```
allpieces = ["Queen", "Tower", "Rook"]
mlist = ["Pawn", "Queen", "Rook"]
l = []

for c in allpieces:
    if c in mlist:
        l.append({"piece": c, "type": "m"})
    else:
        l.append({"piece": c, "type": "b"})

print(l)
```

Which creates a list with our dictionaries inside as such:

```
[{'piece': 'Queen', 'type': 'm'}, {'piece': 'Tower', 'type': 'b'}, {'piece': 'Rook', 'type': 'm'}]
```

Now if you were to access elements within this list you would do `l[0]["piece"]` to get `"Queen"`

Comment: The output you posted is indeed exactly what I am looking for, the problem is that my allpieces and mlist are CSV files and not lists, I need to pull data from allpieces check if it's in mlist and then add it to my list of dictionaries with 'type' : 'm', the comparing thing between the two CSV files is the problem

Comment: @aniani2020 Did you already pull the data from the csv files ? if so how do your lists or dictionaries for allpieces and mlist look like ?

Comment: I have a written library that converts CSV files to relations (tables), my allpieces is then a table with a row that contain piece numbers, and mlist is a table that contain the pieces number of type m (which are already in allpieces)

Comment: So your table objects also look like this ? `[{'piece': 'Queen', 'type': 'm'}, {'piece': 'Tower', 'type': 'b'}]` atleast the way you try access them above makes me think that way. If so you could use `myList = [d['piece'] for d in allpieces]` to get the piece values into a list like I have.